# How can I put my own text hover into default Eclipse editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to put some extra information into to the standard "javadoc" hover, that shows up when you go with mouse over some token. Or I need to create a new hover showing that information while pressing some key (like alt) and then hovering (I can see that this is done e.g. with the shift key, which enables us to see the hover with sourcecode, instead of javadoc).

So far I found documentation on how to create hover in your own editors, but I need to extend the default java editor.

Basically I am interested in showing some e-mail information related to the classname (token) over which user is hovering.

Is there any extension point that could be used for this?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's is an extension point `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers` which you can implement.  The interface which you must implement for this extension point is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.hover.IJavaEditorTextHover`.